# How many ways to form license plates with $10$ digits

Tags: combinatorics

Question:Given $0-9$ digits, $0$ can be leading digit.

a.) How many ways to form a $6$ digits license plates?

b.)If only one digit can be occur more than once, and occurred $3$ times. How many ways are there?

It's easy to see that part a is $10^6$. But I'm stuck on part b, my interpretation is that first we have to count the ways that the digits only occur once. Then we count the second task which is one of the digits occurred $3$ times. I'm stuck on doing the calculation at this moment, any suggestion?

(Note part b is still a $6$ digits license plate)

Answer (score 2):

For part (b), I would approach it the other way around: let's think about the repeated digit first.

1. First, we can have any one of the ten digits to be the repeated one, so that gives us $10$ options to pick it.
2. Then we should pick the three spots for this digit to place it, and that gives us … ways to place it.
3. Finally, for the remaining three spots we need to pick three non-repeating digits: we have $9$ remaining options for the first remaining spot, etc.

Multiplying together, we'll have our answer.

Answer (score 0):

For part (b), first choose the repeated digit: $\binom{10}{1}$, then choose the positions for that digit: $\binom{6}{3}$

Then choose three more distinct digits: $\binom{9}{3}$, and their positions: $3!$

The total is the product of these choices:

$$\binom{10}{1}\times\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{9}{3}\times 3!=100800$$